# the correct way to Load Gif's in asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, animated-gif

I am trying to find a way to correctly load a gif... Apparently the way I am doing it now is causing a mixed content warning on the page.  I have tried using Url.Content(~/path/to/javascript/file) and ResolveClient(~/doesn't/work/either)... What can I do to circumvent this warning?  I will show you my code + the warning I get...

```
function DemoSearchInternals()
{
    //debugger;
    var form = $("#DemoGraphID");
    $div = $("#TabView1");
    var srlzdform = form.serialize();
    var PopID = <% =PopID %>;
    var options = [];
    var $url = $("#target").attr("action");
    //getSize();
    $('<div id="overlay">').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        opacity: 0.2,
        top : $div.offset().top,
        left : $div.offset().left,
        width : $div.width(),
        height : $div.outerHeight(),
        background: 'grey url(<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/images/indicator_web20_working.gif")%>) no-repeat center'
    }).hide().appendTo($div);//Url.Content("~/images/indicator_web20_working.gif")
    $("#overlay").fadeIn();
    $.post('<%:Url.Action("SearchByDemographic", "PatientACO")%>', srlzdform, function (data)
    {
        DisplayDemographicSearch(data);
        $("#overlay").fadeOut('slow', function () {
             $("#overlay").remove();
        });
    });        
}
```

[image: The warning that I get]

I am particularly concerned about the background section?  In an asp.net MVC2 app, is that the best way to call url?  This section:

```
background: 'grey url(<%=Url.Content("~/images/indicator_web20_working.gif")%>) no-repeat center'
```

You see where it says grey url(yadda yadd)  am I calling Url correctly?  Is there a better way to call it?